# Android Studio (4.0) project files are getting deleted after editing and closing the tab

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, android-studio-4.0

Recently I updated to Android Studio 4.0. My issue is when I'm closing the tabs(Java classes) after editing them, some of those files are getting deleted automatically without my knowledge.

When trying to build the project only, I find out that some of the project files(java, XML, gradle files) are missing.

Then I have to check the local history and revert those deleted files every time. (It's labeled as external change list)

[image]

I also have git implemented for the project.

[image: File Missing]

[image: Local History]

Comment: I have the same issue, I tried invalidate cache and upgraded AS to 4.2, nothing help. Now I can not close any tabs. .

Comment: I fixed it by moving the project to another disk/partition.

Comment: Happening to me too in 4.2. Did you find any other solution to this?

Comment: Had the same issue, deleted .idea (and invalidate cache/restart just in case) fixed it

Comment: Never mind -- still happening. Filed an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/202931544, please add your notes or repro steps.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in my case because of the synchronization of the project in iCloud. If you are using a Mac, do not save the project to the Documents and Desktop folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).